# Stream broken up mp3 NSData objects on parse.com without downloading each segment at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming

I'm using parse.com as a backend for my mobile app. I have an mp3 file stored on the backend in broken up nsdata segments. Currently my code appends each separate NSData after being downloaded. This is inefficient and takes too long to load. Could someone provide an example for streaming separate NSData objects? Thanks,

Zack

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to append separate NSData to play and mp3, I think you actually may want to use HTTP Live Streaming.